# How can I do an account transportation?

Tags: support

Is there is a way to transport all account information to another account (votes, badges, questions, answers, ...etc). And then delete the old one.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You could ask for the two accounts to be merged, if I correctly understand what you want.

Comment: @julien merge them but I wanna use one, the new one

Comment: You can just change your username, too, if that's what you're after...

Comment: @mohamez: You should have the ability to edit virtually everything about your current account: the user name, the email-address, the OpenID log-ins associated to it, etc. I really see no reason to simply start a new account only to merge the two.  Is there something specific about your account you want to change that you are uncertain how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [with the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you have a question. That leads to the below link.

The instructions to merge accounts are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)